# MVC - Lazy load 1 string in multiple places

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telerik, lazy-loading

I have recently added some search functionality to my application. It works well, however there is one item, called a `Folder`, that gets searched on that requires me to make a few web service calls. I return a maximum of 100 items at a time, and if all 100 items are specifically this type and require 3 or 4 web service calls each, it takes up to 30 seconds to get the information.

The bit of information that I am getting is a `Path`. The `Path` is the same as a file path on a PC and for every level a new web service call is made. If I remove the code to get this path for each item that is returned, I can get the results to the user in about 2 - 3 seconds with 100 results. This is on my development machine so I am hoping a little faster in production.

What I am trying to do is get the `Path` for each `Folder` after it has been loaded on the screen. This way the majority of the information is already there for the user to see, in an acceptable amount of time, and the `Path` loads a second or two later.

What I have so far is a method in my controller that will return the `Path` as a string:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public string _SearchGetFolderPath(int folderID)
    {
        using (SA sa = new SA())
        using (IRWS irws = new IRWS(sa.Ticket))
        {
            return irws.getFolderPathfromFolderID(folderID);
        }
    }
```

In the above method, the SA object is a user identity for the web service and the IRWS Object is where I am keeping my web service calls.

Then I have this in my view:

```
@*Display Each Returned Result*@
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
                    <h3 class="panel-title pull-left">@(item.Name)</h3>
                    <span class="pull-right">@item.AspectType.AspectName</span>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                        @foreach (var value in item.FieldValues)
                        {
                            <dt>@value.FieldName</dt>
                            @*Test if Item is a Folder and Field is Path*@
                        if (item.AspectType.AspectTypeID == -10 && value.FieldName.Contains("Path"))
                        {
                            /*Folder Path - get path*/
                            //   HERE IS WHERE I WOULD LIKE TO LAZY LOAD THE PATH
                        }
                        else if (false)
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <dd>@value.FieldValue</dd>
                            }

                        }
                    </dl>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
        }
```

I want this to work similarly to how another part of my application works. Each `Folder` has a page that gives more information and I use Telerik for all my UI so I lazy load the `Folder`'s children in a `Panel Bar` (http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/panelbar/ajax).

Any ideas or suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Lazyloading is baked in to C# in some way like the example below that may help:

```
public class yourClassName {
   static object _lock = new object();
   static IDictionary<string, string> loadedValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();


   private string BuildString(int folderID) {
        if (!loadedValues.ContainsKey(folderID)) // if we dont have the value 
            using (SA sa = new SA())
            using (IRWS irws = new IRWS(sa.Ticket))
                lock(this)
                    if (loadedValues.ContainsKey(folderID)) // lets check again (maybe in btween the locks other threads did the job)
                        lock(_lock)
                            return loadedValues[folderID];
                    else // it looks like we dont have it (now it is populated)
                        loadedValues.Add(folderID, irws.getFolderPathfromFolderID(folderID));
        return loadedValues[folderID]
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public string _SearchGetFolderPath(int folderID)
    {
        return BuildString(folderID);
    }

}
```

Lazy loading by nature for me to recommend it it will require me to know little more logic and why is it used.

As an alternative while you are in the MVC.net world you can leverage MVC caching which will save you even more time in this case (controller method will not be invoked and view html/tmplate is cached), simply add the line below as attribute to you method

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 10 /* minutes */, VaryByParam = "folderID")]
```

for more on MVC caching links below

Concepts and how it works
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648482.aspx

How to use / optimize cache
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs

Comment: The problem with caching the path is that the path can change at any time.

Comment: Added the lazy loading and caching based on folder id bit, hope it helps :) 
what you are looking for is not lazy loading if the value changes (thinking that the using statement is not the expensive lines but the "getFolderPath" is the expensive line)

Comment: You are correct, that `irws.getFolderPathfromFolderID(folderID)` has a loop in it that will get the details for the next child until it has a full path. Maybe I should just make it work the old fashion way... A button for each path. haha.